# Python dictionaries copy

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to transform the list of the dictionary from one format to another:

input format:

```
safe_directions = [{'user':'user1', 'direction':'down' }, {'user':'user1', 'direction':'right' }, {'user':'user1', 'direction':'left'}, {'user':'user2', 'direction':'up'}]
```

I am trying transform it into:

output :

```
[
{'user':'user1',
 'run': {'up':False, 'down':True, 'right':True, 'left':True}
 },

{'user':'user2', 
 'run': { 'up':True, 'down':False, 'right':False, 'left':False}
 }
]
```

I am trying to transform this, but I feel stuck with python object reference. In the end user2 has all runs marked as True.
Here is my code:

```
def is_safe():

    template = {'user':None,
                    'run':{
                        'up':False,
                        'down':False,
                        'right':False,
                        'left':False
                    }
    }

    safe_directions = [{'user':'user1', 'direction':'down' }, {'user':'user1', 'direction':'right' }, {'user':'user1', 'direction':'left'}, {'user':'user2', 'direction':'up'}]

    direction_map = {}

    if not safe_dir['user'] in direction_map.keys():
        direction_map[safe_dir['user']] = template.copy()

    # The above line seems does not create new copy?
    print(direction_map.values())
```

My output:

```
[
{'user': 'user1', 
'run': {'up': True, 'down': True, 'right': True, 'left': True}
}, 

{'user': 'user2', 
'run': {'up': True, 'down': True, 'right': True, 'left': True}
}
]
```

Here all my run/directions become true in direction_map directiory. After debugging code, found that only single reference of currrent_dir is maintained.
Could anyone please suggest any pointers?

Comment: 1. Please don't shadow the python builtin `input`, use some other var name.
2. If the dict keys `'run'` and `'user'` are not necessary, wouldn't it be better to use this structure?
`{'user1': {'up': True, 'down': True, 'right': True, 'left': True}, 'user2': {'up': True, 'down': True, 'right': True, 'left': True}}`
This eliminates useless keys and makes your code more readable (to me at least)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code. My input and output format is expected format and can't be changed.

Comment: In that case, stick with the original because it matches with the output format. Is this for hw or something?

Answer (score 2):

Every copy of template contains a reference to the *same* `run` value dictionary.  You need a deep copy to make unique copies of mutable values:

Use:

```
import copy
direction_map[safe_dir['user']] = copy.deepcopy(template)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation.  `copy` is only a shallow copy: one level deep.  Everything under that first level is a reference.  Therefore, `user1` and `user2` are sharing the same sub-dicts.

```
import copy

...

            direction_map[safe_dir['user']] = copy.deepcopy(template)
```

Output:

```
{'user': 'user1', 'run': {'up': False, 'down': True, 'right': False, 'left': False}}
{'user': 'user1', 'run': {'up': False, 'down': True, 'right': True, 'left': False}}
{'user': 'user1', 'run': {'up': False, 'down': True, 'right': True, 'left': True}}
{'user': 'user2', 'run': {'up': True, 'down': False, 'right': False, 'left': False}}
dict_values([{'user': 'user1', 'run': {'up': False, 'down': True, 'right': True, 'left': True}}, {'user': 'user2', 'run': {'up': True, 'down': False, 'right': False, 'left': False}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `defaultdict` in this case.
Here you go.

```
from collections import defaultdict

run_template = {'down': False, 'right': False, 'left': False, 'up':False}
def_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for i in safe_directions:
    if i['user'] not in def_dict: def_dict[i['user']].update(run_template)
    def_dict[i['user']].update({i['direction'] : True})

direction_map = [{k:v} for k,v in def_dict.items()]
print(direction_map)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should do it -

```
safe_directions = [{'user':'user1', 'direction':'down' }, {'user':'user1', 'direction':'right' }, {'user':'user1', 'direction':'left'}, {'user':'user2', 'direction':'up'}]

l = []

for dic in safe_directions:
    if not l or l and l[-1]['user'] != dic['user']:
        l.append({'user': dic['user'], 'run': {'up': False, 'down': False, 'right': False, 'left': False}})
    l[-1]['run'][dic['direction']] = True
```

Then `l` will equate to

```
[{'user': 'user1', 'run': {'up': False, 'down': True, 'right': True, 'left': True}}, {'user': 'user2', 'run': {'up': True, 'down': False, 'right': False, 'left': False}}]
```

Comment: @User007 - could you please try the code I have added above and see if that works for you?